# libv8 fail during mini_racer gem install inside docker ruby image on Apple Mac M1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, docker, apple-m1

I have a simple dev environment working on Intel Mac host, but when in new M1 this error occur during `bundle install`. Before this error I'm getting something about don't have python2 inside container, solved this by doing a `apt-get python2` before run bundle. **I just tried --with-system-v8 but the error still there**.

The environment:

- Host: MBP M1;
- Docker 3.3.3;
- Image: ruby:2.6.5-slim-buster; (tried upgrade to armv64 2.6.7 and still getting the same error)
- bundler: 2.2.9; (just tried to downgrade 2.1.4 and upgrade to 2.2.16 without success)

```
#11 544.5 [0:02:45] Still working on:
#11 544.5 [0:02:45]   v8
#11 544.5 ________ running 'vpython third_party/depot_tools/update_depot_tools_toggle.py
#11 544.5 --disable' in '/usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor'
#11 544.5 /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor/depot_tools/.cipd_bin/.cipd/pkgs/0/KTXfqwOx-7vF-latasoNKn2BBMYj93pSpoVyUjBxR4kC/vpython:
#11 544.5 could not resolve options: failed to resolve Python script: stat
#11 544.5 /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor/third_party/depot_tools/update_depot_tools_toggle.py:
#11 544.5 no such file or directory
#11 544.5 Error: Command 'vpython third_party/depot_tools/update_depot_tools_toggle.py
#11 544.5 --disable' returned non-zero exit status 1 in
#11 544.5 /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/vendor
#11 544.5 Running: gclient root
#11 544.5 Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
#11 544.5   {
#11 544.5     "name": "v8",
#11 544.5     "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
#11 544.5     "deps_file": "DEPS",
#11 544.5     "managed": False,
#11 544.5     "custom_deps": {},
#11 544.5   },
#11 544.5 ]
#11 544.5 '
#11 544.5 Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads
#11 544.5 Subprocess failed with return code 2.
#11 544.5 /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/builder.rb:83:in `block in
#11 544.5 setup_build_deps!': unable to fetch v8 source (RuntimeError)
#11 544.5   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/builder.rb:81:in `chdir'
#11 544.5 from /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/builder.rb:81:in
#11 544.5 `setup_build_deps!'
#11 544.5 from /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in
#11 544.5 `build_libv8!'
#11 544.5 from /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in
#11 544.5 `install!'
#11 544.5   from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'
#11 544.5
#11 544.5 extconf failed, exit code 1
#11 544.5
#11 544.5 Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-8.4.255.0 for
#11 544.5 inspection.
#11 544.5 Results logged to
#11 544.5 /usr/local/bundle/extensions/aarch64-linux/2.6.0/libv8-8.4.255.0/gem_make.out
#11 544.5
#11 544.5 An error occurred while installing libv8 (8.4.255.0), and Bundler cannot
#11 544.5 continue.
#11 544.5 Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '8.4.255.0'` succeeds before bundling.
#11 544.5
#11 544.5 In Gemfile:
#11 544.5   mini_racer was resolved to 0.3.1, which depends on
#11 544.5     libv8
```